# Why is my Python object gets initialized incorrectly in an IPython notebook?

Tags: python, ipython, python-3.6

I have following classes, which I used in a IPython 3.6 notebook:

```
class LaborResult:
    value = Value()
    quantity = 0.0 

class Value:
    absolute = 0
    relative = 0
    service = 0
    def add(self, anotherValue):
        self.absolute = self.absolute + anotherValue.absolute
        self.relative = self.relative + anotherValue.relative
        self.service = self.service + anotherValue.service
    def str(self):
        return 'Value(abs=' + str(self.absolute) + ', rel=' + str(self.relative) + ', srv=' + str(self.service) + ')'
```

I found out that `value.relative` is initialized to a wrong value (12 instead of 0) in some cases.

When I execute

```
x = Value()
x.str()
```

I get the correct result:

```
'Value(abs=0, rel=0, srv=0)'
```

When I change the code to

```
y = LaborResult()
y.value.str()
```

the result is

```
'Value(abs=0, rel=12, srv=0)'
```

I don't see where `rel=12` came from.

Unfortunately, this error does not occur, if I remove all the other code (i. e. isolate only those two classes). What are possible causes of such behavior and how to fix it (make sure that `y.value.relative == 0` in the second example)?

**Update:**

The error disappeared after I rewrote it as:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self):
        self.absolute = 0.0
        self.relative = 0.0
        self.service = 0.0
    def add(self, anotherValue):
        self.absolute = self.absolute + anotherValue.absolute
        self.relative = self.relative + anotherValue.relative
        self.service = self.service + anotherValue.service
    def str(self):
        return 'Value(abs=' + str(self.absolute) + ', rel=' + str(self.relative) + ', srv=' + str(self.service) + ')'

class LaborResult:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = Value()
        self.quantity = 0.0
```

Comment: Why is everything declared at the class level instead of in an `__init__` method? There's a chance that the class-level attributes are what is causing the issue

Comment: `y.value.str()` does *not* produce that output. That said, I'm pretty sure I know what your problem is.

Comment: Also, why do use define a method `str` instead of overriding `__str__` or `__repr__`?

Comment: Let me know if the dupe is wrong and I'll reopen. But then you'll have to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Thanks. That seems to have caused the problem (see update in my question).

Comment: @EdwardMinnix Re `str`: Because I'm new to Python :)